# Change \endhead in the middle of a longtable

Tags: longtable

I am creating many longtables in my document, where one table represents the results of a specific topic. Normally the header of the longtable consists of the name of the topic, N and some cmidrules. If the table has to break at some point, the new header changes the name of the topic to topic (cont.).

Now sometimes a topic has two subquestions. If the table breaks after the second question I would like to change the endhead to include the second question. Here is a short MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{lc}
\toprule
Question 1 & N \\
\cmidrule(r){1-1}
\cmidrule(l){2-2}
\endfirsthead
\toprule
Question 1 (cont.) 1 & N \\
\cmidrule(r){1-1}
\cmidrule(l){2-2}
\endhead
\bottomrule\endfoot
Item 1 & 4 \\
Item 2 & 10 \\
Item 3 & 2 \\
Item 4 & 8 \\
Item 5 & 20 \\
Item 6 & 3 \\
Item 7 & 6 \\
Item 8 & 1 \\
Item 9 & 11 \\
Item 10 & 6 \\
& \\

Question 2   & N \\
\cmidrule(r){1-1}
\cmidrule(l){2-2}
Item 1 & 4 \\
Item 2 & 10 \\
Item 3 & 2 \\
Item 4 & 8 \\ \newpage
Item 5 & 20 \\
Item 6 & 3 \\
Item 7 & 6 \\
Item 8 & 1 \\
Item 9 & 11 \\
Item 10 & 6 \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Now if the table breaks it would write Question 1 (cont.), but I would like it to be Question 2 (cont.). Is there a way to achieve that goal with longtable or is it possible to build a newcommand like

```
\newendhead{
Question 2 (cont.)  & N \\
\cmidrule(r){1-1}
\cmidrule(l){2-2}
}
```

which I can insert at a certain point in the table?

Answer (score 4):

You can use two longtables, but arrange that they share the same column widths:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\makeatletter
\ifx\LT@ii\@undefined\else
\def\LT@entry#1#2{\noexpand\LT@entry{-#1}{#2}}
\xdef\LT@i{\LT@ii}
\fi
\endgroup
\begin{longtable}{lc}
\toprule
Question 1 & N \\
\cmidrule(r){1-1}
\cmidrule(l){2-2}
\endfirsthead
\toprule
Question 1 (cont.) 1 & N \\
\cmidrule(r){1-1}
\cmidrule(l){2-2}
\endhead
\bottomrule\endfoot
Item 1 & 4 \\
Item 2 & 10 \\
Item 3 & 2 \\
Item 4 & 8 \\
Item 5 & 20 \\
Item 6 & 3 \\
Item 7 & 6 \\
Item 8 & 1 \\
Item 9 & 11 \\
Item 10 & 6
\end{longtable}

\begin{longtable}{lc}
\toprule
Question 2 & N \\
\cmidrule(r){1-1}
\cmidrule(l){2-2}
\endfirsthead
\toprule
Question 2 (cont.) 1 & N \\
\cmidrule(r){1-1}
\cmidrule(l){2-2}
\endhead
\bottomrule\endfoot
\cmidrule(r){1-1}
\cmidrule(l){2-2}
Item 1 & 4 \\
Item 2 & 10 \\
Item 3 & 2 \\
Item 4 & 8 \\ \newpage
Item 5 & 20 \\
Item 6 & 3 \\
Item 7 & 6 \\
Item 8 & 1 \\
Item 9 & 11 \\
Item 10000widdddeeer col& 6 \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

If you need more than two, you need the weird code before each except the last, making in each case `\LT@<thistable>` be defined to be `\LT@<the last>` table>

Answer (score 4):

**Attention:**  This is not really meant as code usable in a real document as I didn't test it a lot. But I was curious if one can exchange the longtable headers in the middle of a table and this is the result.

The header of a longtable is stored in a box (`\LT@head`) and when a longtable chunk is output at the top of the page this box is added. The box is stored at the `\endhead` command. It is quite possible to have more than one `\endhead` in a table as long as they are all at the start of longtable. The last will win. It is also possible to exchange the `LT@head` in the middle of the table. The main problem is to do it in the right moment so that it isn't used too early, a small LTchunksize is useful here.

It is probably not a good idea to do this with boxes with different height.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\newbox\LTheadsave
\makeatletter
\newcommand\saveLThead{\noalign{\global\setbox\LTheadsave\copy\LT@head}}
\newcommand\restoreLThead{\noalign{\global\setbox\LT@head\copy\LTheadsave}}
\makeatother

\setcounter{LTchunksize}{2}
\begin{longtable}{lc}
\toprule
Question 1 & N \\
\cmidrule(r){1-1}
\cmidrule(l){2-2}
\endfirsthead
\toprule
Question 2 (cont.) 1 & N \\
\cmidrule(r){1-1}
\cmidrule(l){2-2}
\endhead\saveLThead
\toprule
Question 1 (cont.) 1 & N \\
\cmidrule(r){1-1}
\cmidrule(l){2-2}
\endhead

\bottomrule\endfoot
Item 1 & 4 \\
Item 2 & 10 \\
Item 3 & 2 \\
Item 4 & 8 \\
Item 5 & 20 \\
Item 6 & 3 \\
Item 7 & 6 \\
Item 8 & 1 \\
Item 9 & 11 \\
Item 10 & 6 \\
& \\\newpage
Item 1 & 4 \\
Item 2 & 10 \\
Item 3 & 2 \\
Item 4 & 8 \\
Item 5 & 20 \\
Item 6 & 3 \\
Item 7 & 6 \\
Item 8 & 1 \\
Item 9 & 11 \\
Item 10 & 6 \\
&\\

Question 2   & N \\
\cmidrule(r){1-1}
\cmidrule(l){2-2}
Item 1 & 4 \\\restoreLThead
Item 2 & 10 \\
Item 3 & 2 \\
Item 4 & 8 \\
Item 5 & 20 \\
Item 6 & 3 \\\newpage
Item 7 & 6 \\
Item 8 & 1 \\
Item 9 & 11 \\
Item 10 & 6 \\
\end{longtable}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes wondered about that too:-) As always there's some variablity in when that gets executed relative to the output routine breaking the page, but as there is typically no vertical flexibility in a table, in practice the output routine always triggers in the only possible breakpoint so this is probably safe enough if chunksize is small

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: One could probably move the restore command a bit down to be on the safe side - after rethinking: if it is to much down it could come to late. The main question is what should happen if the pagebreak is directly before question 2?