# Progressive and recursive numbering in longtable

Tags: longtable

I am writing a `longtable`. That package provides a way to automate some text at the end of the table on every page and at the beginning of the table of every page.

I want something that can generate these two lines -

1. Continued on page (current page no. + 1)
2. Continued from page (current page no. -1)

I've written this sample code -

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\LARGE\begin{longtable}{|c|}
\hline
\\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\hline
Continued from \the\numexpr\value{page}-1\relax\\
\hline
\hline
\endhead
\hline
Continued on \the\numexpr\value{page}+1\relax\\
\hline
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
abcdefghijklm\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

This code produces an output where the page no. is constant & it is same as of the first page. What should be added or changed in this code to make it look the *current* page no. & not the one where the commands are placed?

Comment: the header and footer are boxes, they don't change. There are a number tricks (and somewhere a patch to the output routine of longtable) see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263597/change-endhead-in-the-middle-of-a-longtable/263612#

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand the connection between the answer referred by you and my question.

Comment: The code in longtable simply does not support the feature that you ask for. As Ulrike says it is (always) possible to change things, it is all open source but it requires fairly major changes to the longtable implementation.